# How to get the size of the screen with Gtk?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I'm trying to get the size of the monitor with a C Gtk program.

I saw this version, but these functions are deprecated since Gtk 3.22:

```
gint width  = gdk_screen_width();
gint height = gdk_screen_height();
```

In the GdkScreen documentation, I only found: "Use per-monitor information".

I tried to find any information about that in the GdkMonitor or GdkDisplay documentation, but had no success.

The only similar function is:

```
int gdk_monitor_get_width_mm (GdkMonitor *monitor);
```

But it's not what I am looking for.

Does anyone have an idea on how can I get these informations?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `gdk_monitor_get_geometry()` and `gdk_monitor_get_workarea()`?

Comment: Should I do something like that :

`display = gdk_display_get_default();
 monitor = gdk_display_get_monitor(display, 0);
 gdk_monitor_get_geometry(monitor, &r);`

Doing so returns me 0, 0 in the r variable.

Comment: You could use functions from another API to get the size of the screen (like `GetSystemMetrics` on Windows). You want to do this specifically  with functions from Gtk?

Comment: @T.Gros that looks ok. Can you show the actual code that gives you "0, 0"?

Comment: I don't want to use Gtk functions specifically, but I would like something that works in a cross-platform application. Since I'm using Gtk, I think it could be easier no? (I'm working on a MacOS / Unix environment, by the way).

Comment: @jku All right, I'm just an idiot. I was printing the x and y values instead of width and height, for the GtkRectangle...Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

I have to work out aspect ratio's per monitor however - 
Gtk+ Functions Depreciate So Fast: but ended up with this:

```
GdkRectangle workarea = {0};
gdk_monitor_get_workarea(
    gdk_display_get_primary_monitor(gdk_display_get_default()),
    &workarea);

printf ("W: %u x H:%u\n", workarea.width, workarea.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using Gtk
win = GtkWindow()
maximize(win)
sleep(0.1)
window = GtkWindow("Title", width(win), height(win))
destroy(win)
maximize(window)

screen size : width(win), height(win
```

Comment: I have only just started with Gtk in Julia, but have wangled this one out. Please comment should it have unseen errors.

Comment: I don't know Julia, but should the last paren be closed?

Comment: You're getting downvoted because the question wants an answer written in C code.