How to get screen height and width in pixcels instead of mm?
Before GDK version 3.28, I got screen height and width in pixels by gdk_screen_height() and gdk_screen_width(), but both get deprecated since version 3.22 and the GDK documentation suggests that "Use per-monitor information".
So, instead of directly using deprecated functions, I've got GdkMonitor as follows:
GdkDisplay *display = gdk_display_get_default();
GdkWindow* gdkwindow = gdk_get_default_root_window ();
GdkMonitor* monitor = gdk_display_get_monitor_at_window (display, gdkwindow);

The problem here is that GdkMonitor only has functions that return in mm units like gdk_monitor_get_height_mm() and gdk_monitor_get_height_mm, no functions return in pixels units.
How can I convert these mm units' values to pixel units?
Or, Have I missed something that "Use per-monitor information" suggested by the GDK document?

Is this answering your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225956/how-to-get-the-size-of-the-screen-with-gtk ?

I tried the code, but the height value is different between gdk_screen_height() as 1048 and workarea.height as 1012.

cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size on the RPi report as 1872,1048. So the correct value is from gdk_screen_height(), not workarea.height.

GTK authors decided that an application doesn't need to know entire screen resolution. Probably 32 pixels is height of desktop manager panel.

Might be so. So, if there is general (means works well on Linux, Mac, etc) function to get desktop manager panel size, the result value of this function + workarea.height can be a substitution of gdk_screen_height(), but not….

Application may run in different environments, e.g. with two panels, with vertical panel, virtual screen panning, no window manager at all, etc. I think  only non-portable backend-dependent methods may give you real resolution.

I've found that the height of the Desktop manager is 36 pix. So, the cause of the 32 pixel difference is now unknown.

Did you try gdk_monitor_get_geometry()? BTW, where did you get gdk version 3.28? Typo?

Thanks dimich! It returns same width and height! And 3.28 is typo as 3.24 as you imagine!
